# Error Thrown In 'Memory' While Using Mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I'm trying to load an arbitrary amount of images into a vector (`imageVector`) while utilising multithreading. I wrote this, but it throws a C2661 error in the file 'memory', saying that `std::tuple` doesn't have an overload that takes 4 arguments

I believe it's something to do with `threads.push_back...`, as the error changes when I comment it out

```cpp
std::mutex safeGuard, threadWait;
std::condition_variable holdThread;
std::vector<std::thread*> threads;

for (std::vector<std::wstring>::iterator it = g_vecImageFileNames.begin(); it != g_vecImageFileNames.end(); it++) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(threadWait);
    holdThread.wait(lock, [threads](){return threads.size() >= std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); });
    threads.push_back(new std::thread(loadImageMutex, *it, imageVector, safeGuard));
    threads.back()->join();
}
```

Comment: What is the signature of your `loadImageMutex` function?

Comment: Also note that this will not give you any parallelism, because you join each thread sequentially before creating the next one.

Comment: What's the point of the condition variable? Where were you planning on signaling it to wake the threads up?